# Keymap/lmap and recursive mapping in vim

Tags: vim

I'm using a keymap to type non-latin characters in vim. Like that: `set keymap=russian-jcukenwin`. E.g. that maps `q` to `й` and `@` to `"`. The problem is that I can neither redefine/remove such mapping with `lmap`/`lunmap` nor define a recursive mapping, e.g. to map `"` to something else (and that breaks all mappings in vim-latexsuite and makes me sad).

The only idea I've got now is not to use `keymap` - and `lmap` all the keys manually.

So, is there any better workaround?

Comment: Can't you just copy the russian-jcukenwin file to another name and modify the content to suit your need, that is, comment out the mappings that you don't want?

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a nice idea.